# How to store search results for localization

Tags: python, json, search, solr, localization

I have search results similar to as follows:

```
search.get_res()
{
  "Title": "The Lion King",
  "Synopsis": "When the evil Scar kills Mufasa..."
  "RunTime": 92
}
```

However, I also need to **localize** the `Title` and `Synopsis` if the user is using a different language. In other words, I need to be able to specify something like:

```
search.get_res(language="en")
search.get_res(language="fr")
search.get_res(language="de")
```

What would be the best way to store this? Should this all be in one json object? Perhaps something like:

```
{
    "DEFAULT": {
        "Title": "The Lion King",
        "Synopsis": "When the evil Scar kills Mufasa..."
        "RunTime": 92
    }, "FR": {
        "Title": "Le Grande Lion",
        "Synopsis": "Quande elle..."
    }
}
```

Or, what would be the best way to store a solr search result where some (not all, only some) of the information is localized and could be localized in up to 50 languages. 50 synopses could get quite large if everything was stored in the same json object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to **search and display** results in multiple languages. If thats the case, then there are two strategies

1. Multi core configuration. Each language has its own core, and on the application side, you specify which core to search, based on what language the user has selected.
2. Single core configuration, with duplicate fields for each language - More or less the same solution you are thinking of.

I found two websites which go into details of the above configurations. 
http://www.basistech.com/indexing-strategies-for-multilingual-search-with-solr-and-rosette/
http://pavelbogomolenko.github.io/multi-language-handling-in-solr.html

In case you want just the option of displaying the results in different languages but keep the search limited to english, the solution might be simpler. 
Example doc

```
{
    "Doc1": {
        "EN_Title": "The Lion King",
        "EN_Synopsis": "When the evil Scar kills Mufasa..."
        "FR_Title": "Le Grande Lion",
        "FR_Synopsis": "Quande elle..."
    }
}
```

In the Solr search you specify the return fields as

`&fl=FR_*` (for french) or

`&fl=EN_*` (for english)

Comment: thanks for this. Would there be any disadvantage of using route #2? It seems that would be a much simpler approach if there aren't any big disadvantages of storing so much text in one json obj.

Comment: The only disadvantage I can think of is the document size which will increase as you add more languages. This in turn will increase your single collection/share index size. Querying a single large index will be slower. But you might Not notice the difference if you have only a few millions documents hosted on SOLR servers with good amount of RAM. I can't give specific numbers since it depends on a lot of other factors.